# Cloth simulator, but with different densities

Tags: cloth-simulation

I have a need... to throw some clothes on the ground, simply put.
Normally I'd do a cloth simulation, but now I'm dealing with clothes that have elements that, unlike the rest of the dress need to stay rigid.
I'll give an example: a bra.
Of course, the straps must be able to go all over the place, but the cups must remain rigid, during the simulation.

Or, more trivially, pants with a metal zipper. This must remain rigid... affecting the fabric around it, I might add.

How can I do?

Answer (score 3):

you can use the property weights for that behaviour:

[image]

define a vertex group, choose it e.g. as bending group and change the max bending.

I did this in this example and colored it red and blue so you can hopefully better see the difference between the behaviour / bending.

[image]